# Wordpress пагинация работает только на главной (index.php)

Tags: wordpress, pagination

На [сайте](http://test.mobile99.ru) пагинация (постраничная навигация) работает только на главной, почему?

Один и тот же код на главной и на странице "Наши объекты". Но на главной пагинация работает (пробовал разные реализации), а на странице "Наши объекты" пагинация не выводится вообще!

```
<div class="container-fluid visible-md-block visible-lg-block about-us">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="our-objects">
            <h2 class="about-us-h2">Примеры некоторых наших объектов за сезон 2016г.</h2>
                <?php $query_obj_gal = new WP_Query(array ( 
                        'category_name' => 'obj_gal',
                        'posts_per_page' => 2,
                        'post_type'  => 'post',
                )); ?>          
                <?php if ($query_obj_gal->have_posts()) : while (       
                    $query_obj_gal->have_posts()) : $query_obj_gal->the_post()?>

                    <h3 class="bold"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>  
                    <?php the_content(); ?>     

                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>     
                <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>    
                <?php //wp_corenavi(); ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Кастомные циклы в wordpress должны содержать параметр `'paged'`, иначе wordpress "не понимает", какая страница пагинации должна выводиться. Пример:

```
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args=array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'paged' => $paged,
        );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'content' );
        }
        if ($query->max_num_pages > 1) {
        previous_posts_link('< Предыдущая страница');
        next_posts_link( 'Следующая страница >', $query->max_num_pages );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
```

Этот пример работает у меня. Надеюсь, поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Функция posts_nav_link() работает с основным циклом WordPress, используя данные о цикле в глобальной переменной $wp_query. Вы же используете пользовательский цикл, создавая свой запрос `new WP_Query`.

На одиночной странице никакого основного цикла WordPress нет. Точнее, он содержит одну вашу страницу "Наши объекты". Потому пагинация и не выводится.

По той же причине и на главной пагинация не работает как надо - по клику осуществляется переход на ту же самую страницу.

Суммируя, можно сказать: проблема в том, что posts_nav_link() никак не связана с вашим циклом `new WP_Query`.

Comment: Переписал, используя основной цикл вордпресс - не помогло
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
     <h3 class="bold"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>  
           <?php the_content(); ?>   
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>

Comment: Нельзя использовать основной цикл внутри основного цикла!

Comment: У вас правильно как раз был организован кастомный цикл

Comment: Здесь где ошибка не пойму? <?php if ( have_posts() ) :  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <!-- 
 здесь формирование вывода постов,
 где работают теги шаблона относящиеся к the loop, например, the_title()
 -->
 <h3 class="bold"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>  
 <?php the_content(); ?>  
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: огромное спасибо, помогло! если еще поможете то буду очень благодарен, а как вывести чтобы не просто следующая и предыдущая страницы были, а еще чтобы нумерация была? 1 2 3 ....

Comment: Откройте новый вопрос, а если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.